# SSL certificate to communicate between Exacttarget and private domain

Tags: marketing-cloud, app-development, ssl

We are going to develop **Custom Trigger** and store it on our servers.  One of prerequisites is a public IP which supports SSL.

But, how do we need to configure SSL Handshake between two servers?

Here is the procedure

https://github.com/ExactTarget/journey-builder-custom-hello-world#pre-requisites

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handshake is done over natural HTTPS connections (SSL/port 443).

Configuring your server/endpoint to be SSL-enabled doesn't require any involvement with ExactTarget, except to ensure your SSL-chain is valid.

We recommend that you perform a standard "production-grade" CSR (Certificate Signing Request) and use a trusted CA to authenticate your SSL. This simplifies the process of certificate validation and verification (self-signed certificates can be problematic).

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it does. But, currently, we have to use self-signed certificate for development. Later, we will purchase valid certificate. We have to solve issue with self-signed certificates...

Comment: Journey Builder doesn't support self signed certificates. If you use Heroku, they provide a valid cert. chain that Journey Builder can use.